# Comparing mean percentages - is the one sample t-test applicable?

Tags: r, t-test, percentage

In my dataset, each participant has a percentage score (number of correct answers divided by number of valid answers and later multiplied by 100). I would like to see if the mean of that percentage score is significantly different from the reference mean (a value from previous studies). Is it possible to use the one-sample t-test to compare these mean percentages?

If a one-sample t-test is not applicable, would a one-sample Wilcoxon test be better? If that were the case, how should I tackle the issue of having to compare means? As far as I know, a one-sample Wilcoxon test is not necessarily suited for comparing means. The data is strongly left-skewed and the sample size is above 150.